# how to configure Access-Control header to my website page in c# asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#

I have one page each in two project under a solution.  I am not using `MVC`.

below is the code that I have added to my `home.aspx` of `ACCEPTOR` project.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="home.aspx.cs" Inherits="ACCEPTCORS.home" %>
<% Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); %>
<% Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","*"); %>
```

WebMethod that I am calling is below. I have written the code in `home.aspx.cs` file

```
  [WebMethod]
    public static int show()
    {
        int result = 0;

        return result;
    }
```

below is another page of other project named as CORS. From this page I am calling a javascript function. The javascript function in turn is calling the WebMethod of the home.aspx.cs file.

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script src="http://localhost:5314/home.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
```

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<input type="button" onclick="show();" value="fetch data"/>
</div>
</form>
```

The code of the `javascript` is below

```
function show() { 
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'http://localhost:5314/home.aspx/show',
dataType: "json",
async: true,
success: function (data) {

    alert(data.d);
},

failure: function (data) {
    alert('failure');
},
error: function (data) {
    alert('error');
},
})

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you host your application and try to access in JS
http://localhost/[applicationName]/home.aspx/show

Comment: When I run the application, I can access the JS file

Comment: What about [WebMethod] application

Comment: Add this configuration in your application config file
<system.webServer>
<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>

Comment: I  access the [webMethod]

Comment: I have already added the below

    <system.webServer> <httpProtocol> <customHeaders> <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" /> </customHeaders> </httpProtocol> </system.webServer>

Comment: I got the answer, therewas something error in the internet connectivity

Comment: Thank a lot. All of you helped me